# Angular13: Error: Property 'description' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['description']

Tags: angular

I'm trying to fix this error in Angular 13: Property 'description' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['description']. But without success... can anyone help me and explain how to fix?

This is my *.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ScullyRoute, ScullyRoutesService } from '@scullyio/ng-lib';
import {Subscription } from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-articles',
  templateUrl: './articles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./articles.component.scss']
})
export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  posts: ScullyRoute[] = [];
  private routeSub: Subscription | undefined;

  constructor(
    private scullyService: ScullyRoutesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.routeSub = this.scullyService.available$.subscribe(posts => {
      this.posts = posts.filter(post => post.title);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.routeSub?.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

And this is my *.component.html

```html
<div class="list-group mt-3">
    <a *ngFor="let post of posts" [routerLink]="post.route" class="list-group-item
    list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1">{{post.title}}</h5>
        </div>
        <p class="mb-1">{{post.description}}</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What if you change `{{post.description}}` to `{{post['description']}}`

Comment: can you post the interface for ScullyRoute?

Comment: import { ScullyConfig } from '@scullyio/scully';

import '@scullyio/scully-plugin-puppeteer';

export const config: ScullyConfig = {
  projectRoot: "./src",
  projectName: "my-blog",
  outDir: './dist/static',
  routes: {
    '/posts/:id': {
      type: 'contentFolder',
      id: {
        folder: "./mdfiles"
      }
    },
  }
};

Comment: And if I change {{post.description}} to {{post['description']}} is always error: Property '' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['']

Comment: @Drag13 was right: <p class="mb-1">{{post['description']}}</p> is the solution!

Comment: I have the same issue.  I guess you were working through the book *Angular Projects* too?  The solution given by @Drag13 works for me, however, I'm still curious as to what this error message means.  What is this business about "index signature"?

Comment: @workerjoe this mean that `description` was not mentioned as a property. However, the indexer  allows to access it through bracket notation. Simply speaking, TS saying: you can access this prop, but please do it right, as declared on the given type

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are receiving is related to the fact that description is an index signature property of ScullyRoute and must be accessed with brackets notation instead of dot notation.

To fix this error, you need to replace the post.description with post['description'] in your HTML template file:

```
    <div class="list-group mt-3">
        <a *ngFor="let post of posts" [routerLink]="post.route" class="list-group-item
        list-group-item-action">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                <h5 class="mb-1">{{post.title}}</h5>
            </div>
            <p class="mb-1">{{post['description']}}</p>
        </a>
    </div>
```

This should resolve the error and allow you to access the description property of ScullyRoute in your Angular 13 application.